# Cyipopt fails to converge for NLP problem which fmincon() can solve

Tags: optimization, matlab, python, constrained-optimization, nonlinear-programming

I'm currently trying to implement a python script for solving a constrained nonlinear optimization problem with ~800 variables and 2 constraints, one linear and one nonlinear. There already exists a Matlab implementation of this script and I'm trying to use `cyipopt` to implement an equivalent Python implementation that produces similar results.

The Matlab code has analytic solutions for both the objective and constraint and jacobian, which I've rewritten entirely in Python, and uses L-BFGS for hessian approximation. Calling the Python jacobian functions from fmincon() results in the same solution so I think these functions are correct, and I've also used the derivative checkers in both `fmincon()` and `cyipopt` to make sure. However, my Python implementation doesn't converge and fails to match the performance of the Matlab code. In particular, the objective doesn't decrease smoothly. Here's some example output from Ipopt:

```
This is Ipopt version 3.14.4, running with linear solver MUMPS 5.2.1.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:     1602
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        0

Total number of variables............................:      801
                     variables with only lower bounds:        0
                variables with lower and upper bounds:      267
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:        2
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  1.6958872e-01 5.68e-14 1.04e-02   0.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
   1  2.1548097e-01 3.25e+00 7.09e+00   0.6 3.87e+00    -  9.90e-01 4.34e-01f  1
   2  1.7668628e-01 3.05e+00 8.15e+00   0.9 2.38e+00    -  1.00e+00 9.72e-01f  1
   3  1.7381539e-01 1.78e-01 3.39e+00   0.2 1.09e+00    -  7.37e-01 1.00e+00h  1
   4  1.7270930e-01 4.47e-03 2.42e-01  -0.5 2.10e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   5  1.7178940e-01 4.69e-03 4.70e-02  -1.2 7.62e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
   6  1.7055753e-01 5.01e-03 8.89e-03  -1.9 1.21e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   7  1.6692096e-01 1.04e-02 1.15e-03  -2.9 7.68e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   8  1.6323948e-01 3.18e-01 8.33e-03  -3.3 5.42e-01    -  9.42e-01 1.00e+00h  1
   9  1.6005166e-01 1.43e-01 6.64e-03  -9.3 2.50e-01    -  5.61e-01 1.00e+00h  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  10  1.5786474e-01 1.22e-01 4.18e-03  -3.7 4.04e-01    -  7.71e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  11  1.5672747e-01 6.04e-02 5.11e-03  -4.2 1.61e-01    -  9.61e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  12  1.5472463e-01 2.40e-02 2.34e-03  -4.8 1.23e-01    -  9.96e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  13  1.5533721e-01 9.66e-04 6.81e-03  -5.0 1.84e-01    -  9.99e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  14  1.5377085e-01 3.02e-02 3.08e-03  -5.3 1.65e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  15  1.5361137e-01 2.09e-02 4.51e-03  -5.7 1.11e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  16  1.5296208e-01 6.95e-03 1.95e-03  -6.0 8.23e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  17  1.5273048e-01 1.90e-03 1.01e-03  -7.0 3.83e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  18  1.5311695e-01 4.91e-05 5.20e-03  -8.0 2.13e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  19  1.5262106e-01 7.92e-03 6.41e-03  -5.9 4.57e-01    -  1.00e+00 2.30e-01h  2
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  20  1.5261389e-01 1.19e-02 1.27e-02  -3.9 4.90e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.02e-01h  2
  21  1.5310130e-01 4.88e-02 4.09e-03  -3.6 2.90e-01    -  4.10e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  22  1.5330300e-01 2.75e-02 3.72e-03  -3.9 1.29e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  23  1.5201654e-01 1.23e-02 1.40e-03  -3.9 9.69e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  24  1.5227903e-01 3.92e-04 6.45e-03  -4.8 2.11e-01    -  9.86e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  25  1.5495353e-01 1.86e-04 1.26e-02  -4.5 3.70e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  26  1.5557422e-01 3.93e-05 4.07e-03  -4.6 3.53e-01    -  1.18e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  27  1.5281467e-01 7.97e-02 4.35e-03  -4.3 3.09e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  28  1.6236141e-01 3.83e-02 1.24e-02  -4.4 4.15e-01    -  7.25e-01 8.80e-01H  1
  29  1.5299068e-01 8.52e-04 6.17e-03  -4.4 2.48e-01    -  7.17e-02 1.00e+00F  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  30  1.5139425e-01 2.53e-02 3.94e-03  -4.4 9.96e-01    -  2.38e-01 1.55e-01h  3
  31  1.5138493e-01 5.50e-04 3.76e-03  -4.8 2.40e-01    -  9.94e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  32  1.5200809e-01 2.14e-04 5.16e-03  -4.9 1.32e-01    -  9.96e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  33  1.5074554e-01 1.86e-02 1.91e-03  -5.0 1.77e-01    -  9.98e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  34  1.5130813e-01 1.49e-04 3.53e-03  -5.6 1.56e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  35  1.5036412e-01 1.28e-02 1.63e-03  -5.7 1.18e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  36  1.5026330e-01 6.65e-04 8.92e-04  -7.2 3.49e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  37  1.5076495e-01 1.34e-04 5.36e-03  -7.7 1.20e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  38  1.5066012e-01 1.69e-02 6.61e-03  -7.9 1.11e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  39  1.5005302e-01 1.25e-02 1.81e-03  -8.0 1.05e-01    -  5.44e-01 1.00e+00h  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  40  1.5001109e-01 3.87e-03 2.08e-03  -8.6 4.98e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  41  1.4987818e-01 2.98e-03 2.39e-03  -9.7 5.14e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  42  1.5014976e-01 2.70e-05 3.82e-03  -9.8 1.02e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  43  1.4997585e-01 1.01e-02 5.16e-03 -10.4 6.66e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  44  1.4970903e-01 9.51e-03 2.36e-03 -10.5 8.90e-02    -  8.37e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  45  1.4940598e-01 2.37e-03 9.31e-04 -11.0 4.20e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  46  1.4968497e-01 2.68e-05 4.63e-03 -11.0 1.21e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  47  1.4995823e-01 1.29e-06 7.01e-03 -11.0 3.32e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  48  1.4974993e-01 1.46e-02 6.86e-03  -9.0 2.03e+00    -  1.00e+00 1.18e-01f  2
  49  1.4948599e-01 1.72e-02 5.95e-03  -9.1 7.57e-01    -  2.53e-01 8.53e-02h  3
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  50  1.5186145e-01 6.77e-04 8.93e-03  -9.1 2.87e-01    -  7.46e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  51  1.5120058e-01 1.35e-03 4.47e-03  -9.1 3.78e-01    -  1.19e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  52  1.5550082e-01 1.54e-04 8.87e-03  -9.1 3.78e-01    -  5.42e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  53  1.5020757e-01 1.12e-04 4.29e-03  -9.1 4.29e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  54  1.4918169e-01 1.28e-02 1.97e-03  -9.1 1.68e+00    -  2.17e-01 6.23e-02h  3
  55  1.5133875e-01 4.49e-05 8.71e-03  -9.5 2.28e-01    -  9.87e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  56  1.4882545e-01 2.34e-02 2.51e-03  -9.6 1.72e-01    -  4.77e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  57  1.4946850e-01 1.48e-02 6.52e-03 -10.4 1.07e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  58  1.4859822e-01 5.15e-03 2.33e-03 -10.5 6.48e-02    -  9.27e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  59  1.4902635e-01 7.60e-05 4.53e-03 -11.0 1.06e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  60  1.4843429e-01 4.65e-03 1.51e-03 -11.0 7.41e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  61  1.4839694e-01 1.37e-03 2.49e-03 -11.0 3.13e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  62  1.4830507e-01 3.51e-04 8.59e-04 -11.0 2.56e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  63  1.4849382e-01 1.36e-05 5.56e-03 -11.0 1.22e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  64  1.4823266e-01 3.86e-03 1.66e-03 -11.0 9.19e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  65  1.4821480e-01 5.60e-04 1.20e-03 -11.0 1.53e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  66  1.4818681e-01 1.50e-04 2.13e-04 -11.0 1.25e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  67  1.4816045e-01 1.46e-04 5.02e-04 -11.0 1.61e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  68  1.4850582e-01 5.85e-05 5.29e-03 -11.0 1.57e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  69  1.5001793e-01 1.58e-06 1.08e-02 -11.0 1.41e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  70  1.4861627e-01 2.68e-07 5.43e-03 -11.0 2.13e-01    -  2.10e-01 1.00e+00F  1
  71  1.4842174e-01 1.21e-02 4.02e-03 -10.6 3.61e-01    -  1.00e+00 2.50e-01f  3
  72  1.4816338e-01 4.71e-03 2.55e-03 -10.7 6.93e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  73  1.4841277e-01 1.20e-04 5.26e-03 -10.7 1.25e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  74  1.4923205e-01 4.65e-05 7.02e-03 -11.0 9.58e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  75  1.4793006e-01 1.50e-02 1.22e-03 -11.0 1.02e-01    -  9.33e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  76  1.4790107e-01 1.98e-03 2.30e-03 -11.0 4.36e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  77  1.4795403e-01 6.21e-06 2.74e-03 -11.0 3.90e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  78  1.4783354e-01 3.00e-03 1.85e-03 -11.0 5.85e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  79  1.4775646e-01 1.00e-03 1.66e-03 -11.0 2.36e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  80  1.4772077e-01 2.46e-04 8.16e-04 -11.0 1.37e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  81  1.4772337e-01 1.36e-06 1.67e-03 -11.0 2.97e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  82  1.4800983e-01 3.43e-07 4.69e-03 -11.0 1.73e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  83  1.4785970e-01 3.85e-03 5.48e-03 -10.2 1.53e+00    -  1.00e+00 7.61e-02f  3
  84  1.4778198e-01 6.41e-03 6.58e-03 -10.3 3.42e+00    -  6.76e-02 2.92e-02h  3
  85  1.4773098e-01 1.02e-02 5.56e-03 -10.3 2.22e+00    -  6.49e-02 4.72e-02h  3
  86  1.5775339e-01 1.78e-04 7.17e-03 -10.3 1.27e+00    -  1.35e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  87  1.5716495e-01 1.63e-03 5.41e-03 -10.3 1.70e+00    -  1.70e-01 3.17e-02h  4
  88  1.5247575e-01 1.33e-04 4.44e-03 -10.3 3.35e-01    -  5.46e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  89  1.5188072e-01 1.15e-03 3.96e-03 -10.3 1.80e+00    -  7.48e-01 3.87e-02h  5
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  90  1.5109270e-01 2.99e-03 3.54e-03 -10.3 1.65e+00    -  4.22e-01 5.10e-02h  4
  91  1.4947946e-01 5.89e-02 4.20e-03 -10.3 1.50e+01    -  4.46e-02 2.31e-02h  2
  92  1.4898332e-01 5.71e-02 3.70e-03 -10.3 6.05e-01    -  3.30e-01 1.30e-01h  3
  93  1.4893398e-01 4.01e-02 6.60e-03 -10.3 1.73e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  94  1.4813809e-01 2.83e-02 2.88e-03 -10.3 2.64e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  95  1.4953181e-01 5.14e-04 7.13e-03 -10.3 1.61e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  96  1.4757049e-01 2.19e-02 1.86e-03 -10.3 1.12e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  97  1.4838902e-01 1.46e-02 5.65e-03 -10.8 1.05e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  98  1.4742559e-01 8.28e-03 5.50e-04 -10.9 7.16e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  99  1.4739592e-01 1.63e-04 7.52e-04 -11.0 1.75e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
```

Compared to fmincon():

```
                                            First-order      Norm of
 Iter F-count            f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
    0       1    1.695878e-01    5.684e-14    1.102e-02
    1       2    1.691645e-01    1.296e-04    4.729e-03    2.229e-02
    2       3    1.665545e-01    7.175e-03    9.554e-03    1.857e-01
    3       4    1.635913e-01    4.118e-02    6.511e-03    5.518e-01
    4       5    1.626062e-01    3.235e-02    1.080e-02    6.491e-01
    5       6    1.617645e-01    2.861e-02    3.397e-03    7.418e-01
    6       7    1.607960e-01    1.297e-02    2.636e-03    6.037e-01
    7       8    1.595868e-01    4.010e-02    4.019e-03    1.089e+00
    8       9    1.589008e-01    2.304e-02    4.341e-03    7.246e-01
    9      10    1.581489e-01    3.965e-03    1.667e-03    2.636e-01
   10      11    1.575713e-01    1.046e-02    1.000e-03    6.139e-01
   11      12    1.573578e-01    3.968e-03    1.179e-03    4.697e-01
   12      13    1.570832e-01    4.880e-03    1.247e-03    6.278e-01
   13      14    1.567794e-01    5.258e-03    1.000e-03    6.424e-01
   14      15    1.567468e-01    7.916e-03    2.665e-03    6.705e-01
   15      16    1.565624e-01    1.995e-03    1.452e-03    1.778e-01
   16      17    1.565058e-01    9.510e-04    1.309e-03    1.582e-01
   17      18    1.564559e-01    8.874e-04    1.000e-03    2.408e-01
   18      19    1.556438e-01    2.632e-03    7.432e-04    2.010e-01
   19      21    1.542575e-01    1.763e-05    1.908e-03    6.447e-01
   20      23    1.538128e-01    8.862e-06    2.772e-03    3.140e-01
   21      24    1.535477e-01    1.020e-03    1.317e-03    1.241e-01
   22      25    1.531595e-01    2.294e-03    7.816e-04    2.747e-01
   23      26    1.529536e-01    5.902e-04    8.447e-04    1.609e-01
   24      28    1.524555e-01    4.137e-07    1.424e-03    4.367e-01
   25      30    1.521461e-01    2.148e-06    1.428e-03    2.705e-01
   26      31    1.520693e-01    3.572e-04    9.764e-04    7.670e-02
   27      33    1.518785e-01    1.542e-06    1.821e-03    3.113e-01
   28      34    1.516523e-01    7.795e-04    1.052e-03    1.813e-01
   29      35    1.515454e-01    3.468e-04    6.490e-04    1.431e-01
   30      36    1.514033e-01    6.813e-04    7.628e-04    2.445e-01

                                            First-order      Norm of
 Iter F-count            f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
   31      37    1.511966e-01    1.321e-03    1.065e-03    3.590e-01
   32      38    1.509549e-01    2.310e-03    9.453e-04    5.227e-01
   33      39    1.507060e-01    2.390e-03    1.893e-03    5.238e-01
   34      40    1.505274e-01    1.191e-03    4.680e-04    2.007e-01
   35      41    1.504018e-01    3.995e-04    7.486e-04    1.168e-01
   36      42    1.501441e-01    8.662e-04    5.371e-04    3.376e-01
   37      44    1.498647e-01    3.364e-06    1.694e-03    5.798e-01
   38      45    1.496842e-01    9.911e-04    7.416e-04    3.829e-01
   39      46    1.496415e-01    3.685e-04    5.740e-04    1.727e-01
   40      47    1.495934e-01    9.745e-04    1.368e-03    3.101e-01
   41      48    1.494941e-01    6.501e-04    6.743e-04    3.020e-01
   42      49    1.493509e-01    9.861e-04    3.953e-04    3.974e-01
   43      50    1.492265e-01    7.372e-04    6.141e-04    3.550e-01
   44      51    1.490722e-01    1.345e-03    7.354e-04    4.686e-01
   45      52    1.489949e-01    9.143e-04    5.345e-04    2.969e-01
   46      53    1.489130e-01    8.080e-04    7.258e-04    2.955e-01
   47      54    1.488745e-01    1.176e-03    1.445e-03    2.992e-01
   48      55    1.488323e-01    4.312e-04    5.706e-04    1.628e-01
   49      56    1.487758e-01    3.440e-04    8.374e-04    1.993e-01
   50      57    1.486999e-01    1.017e-03    6.874e-04    3.923e-01
   51      59    1.486946e-01    8.701e-06    3.005e-03    4.956e-01
   52      60    1.485959e-01    3.722e-04    9.674e-04    7.810e-02
   53      61    1.485395e-01    3.153e-04    5.199e-04    1.871e-01
   54      62    1.484944e-01    3.883e-04    9.311e-04    2.667e-01
   55      63    1.484078e-01    6.886e-04    1.208e-03    4.148e-01
   56      64    1.482546e-01    2.396e-03    1.258e-03    9.236e-01
   57      65    1.481228e-01    2.799e-03    1.541e-03    9.661e-01
   58      66    1.479890e-01    7.611e-04    5.626e-04    4.157e-01
   59      67    1.478692e-01    1.020e-03    9.555e-04    5.353e-01
   60      68    1.477201e-01    1.205e-03    2.336e-03    6.695e-01

                                            First-order      Norm of
 Iter F-count            f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
   61      69    1.474560e-01    3.556e-03    1.588e-03    1.439e+00
   62      70    1.471856e-01    2.773e-03    1.294e-03    1.377e+00
   63      71    1.469532e-01    1.536e-03    1.162e-03    8.180e-01
   64      72    1.467492e-01    1.390e-03    8.390e-04    7.719e-01
   65      73    1.464826e-01    2.369e-03    2.728e-03    1.328e+00
   66      74    1.461599e-01    2.225e-03    1.697e-03    1.276e+00
   67      75    1.458142e-01    2.839e-03    7.377e-04    1.729e+00
   68      76    1.455273e-01    1.941e-03    1.540e-03    1.555e+00
   69      77    1.451421e-01    2.727e-03    2.188e-03    2.072e+00
   70      78    1.446933e-01    6.136e-03    3.128e-03    2.527e+00
   71      79    1.442774e-01    4.200e-03    1.005e-03    1.977e+00
   72      80    1.440018e-01    1.392e-03    1.141e-03    4.495e-01
   73      81    1.436448e-01    3.002e-03    2.341e-03    1.335e+00
   74      82    1.432150e-01    4.996e-03    3.013e-03    1.999e+00
   75      83    1.427922e-01    3.273e-03    7.698e-04    1.622e+00
   76      84    1.424515e-01    1.755e-03    1.547e-03    1.999e+00
   77      85    1.420710e-01    1.985e-03    1.608e-03    2.162e+00
   78      86    1.414360e-01    5.327e-03    1.684e-03    3.757e+00
   79      88    1.410962e-01    8.909e-05    5.970e-03    7.093e+00
   80      89    1.405116e-01    3.316e-03    1.177e-03    8.055e-01
   81      90    1.402913e-01    1.138e-03    1.549e-03    3.040e-01
   82      91    1.398874e-01    3.111e-03    2.327e-03    1.897e+00
   83      93    1.391672e-01    3.531e-06    3.701e-03    5.891e+00
   84      95    1.383758e-01    5.642e-05    3.542e-03    6.218e+00
   85      96    1.378290e-01    4.166e-03    1.036e-03    2.995e+00
   86      97    1.375162e-01    1.780e-03    1.041e-03    1.597e+00
   87      98    1.370376e-01    5.208e-03    1.925e-03    3.465e+00
   88      99    1.366982e-01    7.099e-03    4.238e-03    3.143e+00
   89     100    1.362886e-01    2.651e-03    2.194e-03    2.074e+00
   90     101    1.360006e-01    2.295e-03    1.189e-03    1.023e+00

                                            First-order      Norm of
 Iter F-count            f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
   91     102    1.358196e-01    9.869e-04    1.742e-03    1.240e+00
   92     103    1.355212e-01    2.761e-03    1.672e-03    1.891e+00
   93     105    1.353705e-01    1.162e-04    4.479e-03    4.375e+00
   94     106    1.348992e-01    2.477e-03    1.632e-03    3.747e-01
   95     107    1.347110e-01    1.267e-03    1.224e-03    3.268e-01
   96     108    1.345712e-01    8.739e-04    1.756e-03    8.004e-01
   97     109    1.343092e-01    3.165e-03    2.251e-03    1.691e+00
   98     111    1.341921e-01    4.984e-03    2.419e-03    1.037e+00
   99     112    1.339379e-01    1.967e-03    9.087e-04    2.052e+00
```

I don't really have any experience with either the theory or practice of optimization, so I'm wondering if anyone can help spot the issue here? Is there any way I can tweak the options I'm passing to IPOPT to solve the problem or is IPOPT simply less suited to this type of optimization problem?

For reference, here's the python code:

```py
class initial_problem():
    def __init__(self, cell_pairs, dC):
        self.cell_pairs = cell_pairs
        self.dC = dC

    def objective(self, x):
        x = x.reshape(x0.shape, order='F')
        q = x[:,0:2]
        p = x[:,2]

        b = np.matmul(self.dC, np.multiply(q.T,p).T)
        delta_p = np.matmul(self.dC, p)

        t1 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T
        t2 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T

        E = 0.5 * np.mean(np.power(np.sum(t1 * tau_1, axis=1), 2) +
                          np.power(np.sum(t2 * tau_2, axis=1), 2))
        return E

    def gradient(self, x):
        # Jacobian of objective
        x = x.reshape(x0.shape, order='F')
        q = x[:,0:2]
        p = x[:,2]

        b = np.matmul(self.dC, np.multiply(q.T,p).T)
        delta_p = np.matmul(self.dC, p)

        t1 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T
        t2 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T

        ip1 = np.sum(t1 * tau_1, axis=1)
        ip2 = np.sum(t2 * tau_2, axis=1)

        drX1 = sx_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r1[:,0], r1[:,1])
        drX2 = sx_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r2[:,0], r2[:,1])
        drY1 = sy_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r1[:,0], r1[:,1])
        drY2 = sy_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r2[:,0], r2[:,1])

        dE = np.multiply(ip1 * tau_1[:,0], drX1.T).T + np.multiply(ip1 * tau_1[:,1], drY1.T).T + \
             np.multiply(ip2 * tau_2[:,0], drX2.T).T + np.multiply(ip2 * tau_2[:,1], drY2.T).T
        dE = dE / self.dC.shape[0]

        rows = np.concatenate([self.cell_pairs[:,0],self.cell_pairs[:,0]+self.dC.shape[1],self.cell_pairs[:,0]+2*self.dC.shape[1],
                               self.cell_pairs[:,1],self.cell_pairs[:,1]+self.dC.shape[1],self.cell_pairs[:,1]+2*self.dC.shape[1]])

        dE = np.bincount(rows, weights=np.ravel(dE,order='F'))
        return dE

    # Define constraints
    def constraints(self, x):
        # linear constraint
        Aeq = np.concatenate((np.zeros(x0.shape[0]*2), np.ones(x0.shape[0])))
        lincon = np.dot(Aeq, x)

        # nonlinear constraint
        x = x.reshape(x0.shape, order='F')
        q = x[:,0:2]
        p = x[:,2]

        b = np.matmul(self.dC, np.multiply(q.T,p).T)
        delta_p = np.matmul(self.dC, p)

        l1 = np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)
        l2 = np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)

        nonlincon = 0.5*(np.mean(l1) + np.mean(l2)) - scale

        cons = np.append(nonlincon, lincon)
        return cons

    def jacobian(self, x):
        # Jacobian of nonlinear constraints
        x = x.reshape(x0.shape, order='F')
        q = x[:,0:2]
        p = x[:,2]

        b = np.matmul(self.dC, np.multiply(q.T,p).T)
        delta_p = np.matmul(self.dC, p)

        t1 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T
        t2 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T

        drX1 = rx_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], r1[:,0])
        drX2 = rx_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], r2[:,0])
        drY1 = ry_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r1[:,1])
        drY2 = ry_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r2[:,1])


        dE = 0.5 * (np.multiply(t1[:,0],drX1.T).T + np.multiply(t1[:,1],drY1.T).T) + \
             0.5 * (np.multiply(t2[:,0],drX2.T).T + np.multiply(t2[:,1],drY2.T).T)

        rows = np.concatenate([self.cell_pairs[:,0],self.cell_pairs[:,0]+self.dC.shape[1],self.cell_pairs[:,0]+2*self.dC.shape[1],
                               self.cell_pairs[:,1],self.cell_pairs[:,1]+self.dC.shape[1],self.cell_pairs[:,1]+2*self.dC.shape[1]])

        dE = np.bincount(rows, weights=np.ravel(dE/self.dC.shape[0],order='F'))

        # Add jacobian of linear constraints
        lin_dE = np.concatenate((np.zeros(2*x0.shape[0]), np.ones(x0.shape[0])))

        jac = np.concatenate([dE, lin_dE])
        return jac

initial_minimization = cyipopt.Problem(
    n = x0.size,
    m = 2,
    problem_obj = initial_problem(self.cell_pairs,self.dC),
    lb = np.concatenate((-np.inf*np.ones(x0.shape[0]), -np.inf*np.ones(x0.shape[0]), 0.001*np.ones(x0.shape[0]))),
    ub = np.concatenate((np.inf*np.ones(x0.shape[0]), np.inf*np.ones(x0.shape[0]), 1000*np.ones(x0.shape[0]))),
    cl = np.array([0, np.mean(p0)*p0.shape[0]]),
    cu = np.array([0, np.mean(p0)*p0.shape[0]])
)

initial_minimization.add_option('max_iter',2000)
initial_minimization.add_option('tol',1e-5)
initial_minimization.add_option('nlp_scaling_method','none')
initial_minimization.add_option('print_timing_statistics','yes')
initial_minimization.add_option('hessian_approximation','limited-memory')

res = initial_minimization.solve(x0.ravel(order='F'))
```

Compared to the original matlab code:

````matlab
energyFunc = @(x) reducedEnergy( x, sparse(d0), t1, t2, r1, r2, bCells );
nonlinFunc = @(x) mycon( x, sparse(d0), Lscale, r1, r2, bCells );

lb = -inf*ones(size(x0));
lb(:,3) = .001;
ub = inf*ones(size(x0));
ub(:,3) = 1000;

Aeq = [zeros(1,size(d0,2)),zeros(1,size(d0,2)),ones(1,size(d0,2))];
beq = size(d0,2)*mean(p);

optimset = optimoptions('fmincon','Display','iter-detailed','Algorithm','interior-point','MaxFunEvals',2e6,...
                        'MaxIter',2e3,'TolFun',1e-5,'GradObj','on','GradConstr','on',...
                        'HessianApproximation','lbfgs');
                    
[x,ERes] = fmincon(energyFunc,x0,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlinFunc,optimset);


function [ clin, ceq, dlin, deq ] = mycon( x, d0, Lscale, r1, r2, bCells )

    NB = size(d0,1);
    NC = size(d0,2);
    q = x(:,1:2);
    p = x(:,3);
    clin = [];
    
    B = d0*bsxfun(@times,q,p);
    deltaP = d0*p;

    B1 = B - bsxfun(@times,deltaP,r1);
    B2 = B - bsxfun(@times,deltaP,r2);

    L1 = sqrt(sum(B1.^2,2));
    B1 = bsxfun(@rdivide,B1,L1);
    
    L2 = sqrt(sum(B2.^2,2));
    B2 = bsxfun(@rdivide,B2,L2);
    
    ceq = .5*(mean(L1) + mean(L2)) - Lscale;
    if (nargout > 2)
        dlin = [];
        deq = .5*(bsxfun(@times,B1(:,1),drX1) + bsxfun(@times,B1(:,2),drY1)) + ...
              .5*(bsxfun(@times,B2(:,1),drX2) + bsxfun(@times,B2(:,2),drY2));
        rows = [bCells(:,1);bCells(:,1)+NC;bCells(:,1)+2*NC;bCells(:,2);bCells(:,2)+NC;bCells(:,2)+2*NC];
        deq = accumarray(rows,deq(:)/NB,[3*NC,1]);
    end
end


function [ E, dE ] = reducedEnergy( x, d0, t1, t2, r1, r2, bCells )
    
    q = x(:,1:2);
    p = x(:,3);

    B = d0*bsxfun(@times,q,p);
    deltaP = d0*p;

    B1 = B - bsxfun(@times,deltaP,r1);
    B2 = B - bsxfun(@times,deltaP,r2);

    L1 = sqrt(sum(B1.^2,2));
    B1 = bsxfun(@rdivide,B1,L1);
    L2 = sqrt(sum(B2.^2,2));
    B2 = bsxfun(@rdivide,B2,L2);

    E = .5*mean( dot(B1,t1,2).^2 + dot(B2,t2,2).^2 );

    if (nargout == 2)
        NB = size(d0,1);
        NC = size(d0,2);
        [ drX1, drY1, drX2, drY2 ] = fitDual.AFN.reducedLocalGrads( q, p, bCells, r1 ,r2 );

        IP1 = dot(B1,t1,2);
        IP2 = dot(B2,t2,2);

        dE = bsxfun(@times,IP1.*t1(:,1),drX1) + bsxfun(@times,IP1.*t1(:,2),drY1) + ...
             bsxfun(@times,IP2.*t2(:,1),drX2) + bsxfun(@times,IP2.*t2(:,2),drY2);
        dE = dE / NB;
        rows = [bCells(:,1);bCells(:,1)+NC;bCells(:,1)+2*NC;bCells(:,2);bCells(:,2)+NC;bCells(:,2)+2*NC];
        vals = dE(:);
        dE = accumarray(rows,vals',[3*NC,1]);

    end
end

```
````

Comment: It appears you are using the same x0 in both solvers because objective & feasibility values are the same on iter 0. FMINCON seems to be doing better than IPOPT, but you don't show us what happened after iter 99. If you want the most robust performance from IPOPT, and can formulate it and evaluates fast enough, supply the "exact" Hessian of the Lagrangian rather than using LBFGS; that will be the Hessian of the objective plus Lagrange multiplier times the Hessian of the nonlinear equality constraint. You could try sr1 instead of lbfgs, but IPOPT might not have  good  SR1. Also, scaling options.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone after iteration 99 the trend is essentially the same, `fmincon()` objective decreases smoothly while IPOPT does not and `fmincon()` eventually reaches a more optimal solution after 2000 iterations. I'm unable to formulate an exact hessian, and sr1 does appear to perform worse than lbfgs.

Comment: In terms of scaling, is the objective just to ensure that the values of the jacobian are within a few orders of magnitude? My constraint jacobian has some values around 10e-1 and some around 10e-4, I'm not sure if this is a large enough difference to be causing the observed issues. Also the `fmincon()` implementation doesn't appear to be scaling the variables either, is there some gradient scaling going on behind the scenes?